# makefile with make 4.0 and include path issue

Tags: makefile, include-path

I have a makefile for kernel module. There is EXTRA_CFLAGS used to pass an include path. But on Debian 3.82 it works ONLY if full path is specified explicitly (hardcoded), if a make function is used like:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -I${PWD}/../include
```

or

```
INC_PATH = $(abspath ${PWD}/../include)
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -I$(INC_PATH)
```

this won't work - file is not found. I checked the output of EXTRA_CFLAGS - it is correct, and this works on other linux with make 3.82.

ADDED:

```
gcc-4.8 -Wp,-MD,/home/user/temp/dmamemory.0/driver/./.DMATestmain.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include -Iinclude -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/kconfig.h   -I/home/user/temp/dmamemory.0/driver -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CRC32=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-var-tracking-assignments -g -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=strict-prototypes -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO   -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/../include  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(DMATestmain)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(dmatest)" -c -o /home/user/temp/dmamemory.0/driver/./.tmp_DMATestmain.o /home/user/temp/dmamemory.0/driver/./DMATestmain.c
```

I found that it runs the $(PWD) inside /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/, not inside Makefile (current) directory. So, EXTRA_CFLAGS looks like:

```
-I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/../include
```

not like:

```
 -I/home/user/temp/dmamemory.0/../include
```

**SOLUTION:**

Use KCFLAGS:

```
${MAKE} -C ${KDIR} M=$(PWD) KCFLAGS="-I$(PWD)/../include"  modules
```

Comment: Show the **exact** command being run that is using that value on the two machines? If the path is the same and the file exists in that location then it will work regardless of how it was specified in the makefile. Also, is this make 3.82 or 4.0?

Comment: Command is: make -C  /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/build M=/home/user/temp/dmamemory.0/driver modules

the EXTRA_CFLAGS is: -O4 -I/home/user/temp/dmamemory.0/include


Yes, the problem that EXTRA_CFLAGS += -I${PWD}/../include doesn't work on one linux (debian 8.3 with make 4.0) and works on other - RedHat with make 3.82

Comment: No. I want the exact command that *fails* during the build. Not the `make` command you are running.

Comment: Compilation fails, not a command. All commands work. But during compilation I see error about No such XX.h file

Comment: Yes, compilation fails. I want to see **that** command. The compilation command that is failing.

Comment: CC [M]  /home/user/temp/dmamemory.0/driver/./DMATestmain.o
/home/user/temp/dmamemory.0/driver/./DMATestmain.c:43:26: fatal error: dmatest_intf.h: No such file or directory
 #include "dmatest_intf.h"
                          ^
compilation terminated.

Comment: You need to turn on verbose mode (`V=1` or whatever that is) so you see the actual command and not just `CC`. Also please put the information in the question so you can format it correctly (and comment that you did so).

Comment: I assume the build uses `make -C` somewhere? You can try using `$(CURDIR)` instead and seeing if that helps. Otherwise I have to assume there's support for this sort of thing built-in. Are you sure you need to do something like this for this to work? Is there a kernel-make-framework provided variable that means "the source directory" you can use?